# I need to find a housing connector for an LED

Tags: led, connector, rgb

I am trying to find a connector for an RGB LED (Mfg P/N: [LZ1-10R102-0000](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/311/LZ1_00R102_EN-2298081.pdf)). I don't want to solder wires onto the board because I want to gift it to my grandparent for easy assembly and change if LED destroyed. Please Suggest me any plugable connector (just like house hold bulb connectors).
Thank you.

Comment: You could solder a connector onto the board and gift them some spares

Comment: LEDs are quite reliable if used with sufficient heatsink and driven at correct power. Could you add additional information of how LED will be used?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what housing or heatsink you are using or even power supply, but if the connector is a problem, you need help and they need something fool proof.

My simple solution would be to attach them to small obsolete circular CPU heatsink so that a fan is not needed for 5W.

For power I would derate 25% approx and run two Red LEDs in series with a Molex connector. You can get that from a scrap PC as well used on HDD’s and use the 2 blk gnds and red 5V for easy connection to a tower or 5.0V >=1A DC regulator with mating socket (F). Then make a cable of suitable gauge for the length.

The wires ought to be soldered then with strain relief like polyurethane subfloor adhesive dabbed around the wire shank or <1cm connection as the solder connection may be fragile.